# Helmholtz decomposition of a vector field in Fourier space with Python

Tags: python, numpy, fft, decomposition

I have a 3D vector field and I want to extract its divergence-free part (also called transverse component), using the Helmholtz decomposition.
In principle, this can be done in the Fourier space, as illustrated [here](https://www.theochem.ru.nl/%7Epwormer/Knowino/knowino.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition.html) in the proof.

I wrote this Python function, implementing this straightforward calculation, where the input is a vector field of shape (3,N,N,N), since it has 3 components and is defined in a 3D square grid with NxNxN nodes and size equal to `boxsize`:

```
def helmholtz_decomposition(vector_field, boxsize):
    kx, ky, kz = np.meshgrid(2 * np.pi * np.fft.fftfreq(vector_field.shape[1], boxsize / (vector_field.shape[1])),
                             2 * np.pi * np.fft.fftfreq(vector_field.shape[2], boxsize / (vector_field.shape[2])),
                             2 * np.pi * np.fft.fftfreq(vector_field.shape[3], boxsize / (vector_field.shape[3])),
                             indexing='ij')

    k_vector = np.array([kx, ky, kz])
    k_squared = kx ** 2 + ky ** 2 + kz ** 2
    k_squared[k_squared == 0] = 1e-12  # Avoid division by zero

    vector_field_fourier = np.fft.fftn(vector_field)

    dot_product = kx * vector_field_fourier[0] + \
                  ky * vector_field_fourier[1] + \
                  kz * vector_field_fourier[2]

    potential_part_fourier = (dot_product / k_squared) * k_vector
    solenoidal_part_fourier = vector_field_fourier - potential_part_fourier

    potential_part = np.real(np.fft.ifftn(potential_part_fourier))
    solenoidal_part = np.real(np.fft.ifftn(solenoidal_part_fourier))

    return potential_part, solenoidal_part
```

Here, the potential and solenoidal parts should be curl-free and divergence-free respectively.

The problem is that the divergence of the solenoidal part is not zero.
I have already checked that the solenoidal part in the Fourier space is perpendicular to the wave vector `k_vector`, as it should be.

Does anyone know where the mistake is?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is it close to zero, like accumulated round-off error close?

Comment: @TimRoberts unfortunately not, because it's even larger than the divergence of the potential component..

Comment: Look, honestly I'm out of my depth here, but I noticed some things.  The proof requires you to take an integral of the FFT on the third derivative and multiply by 1/2pi^(3/2).  I don't see any of those steps.

Comment: @TimRoberts the integrals are performed by the numpy functions fft and ifft: these are the Fourier and the inverse Fourier transforms respectively. Why the third derivative? Thanks for your help

Comment: You're quite right about the integration.  The formula in the proof mentions `d3r` (with the 3 as an exponent), which usually means "third derivative of r".  Again, however, I'm out of my depth.

Comment: @TimRoberts the 3 as exponent means an integration over the 3D space, since r has 3 components. Thank you anyway for your time!!

Comment: I'm currently trying to do essentially the same thing in Julia.  I suspect your issue is with boundary conditions.  On a finite domain, there is a boundary term in the decomposition, c.f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition.

Comment: @Yly thank you very much for the comment. That's a good point. Have you implemented this boundary term?

Comment: @Wil I have not implemented it.  I've found a reference which may be useful: https://www.sci.utah.edu/~hbhatia/pubs/2013_TVCG_survey.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot @Yly , it seems interesting. In the meantime, let me know if you find any workaround!